# How to disable the option in dropdown by selecting in another dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the Grade 11 and Grade 12, if any BSIT, BSCS, etc (all BS) are selected; but if STEM, TOP, GAS and HUMSS are selected the Grade 11 and Grade 12 will be enabled and all BS will be enabled.

```js
var disable_options = false;
document.getElementById('type').onchange = function () {
   //alert("You selected = "+this.value);
   if(this.value == "Student")
   {
      document.getElementById('course').removeAttribute('disabled');
      document.getElementById('year_level').removeAttribute('disabled'); 
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById('course').setAttribute('disabled', true);
      document.getElementById('year_level').setAttribute('disabled', true);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Type:</label>
 <div class="controls">
     <select name="type" id="type" required>
      <option></option>
      <option>Student</option>
      <option>Teacher</option>
      <option>Staff</option>
      <option></option>
            </select>
 </div>
</div>
 
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Course Type:</label>
 <div class="controls">
  <select name="course" id="course" required>
   <option></option>
   <option>BSIT</option>
   <option>BSCS</option>
   <option>BSHRM</option>
   <option>BSBM</option>
   <option>BSTM</option>
   <option>STEM</option>
   <option>TOP</option>
   <option>GAS</option>
   <option>HUMSS</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>    
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Year Level:</label>
    <div class="controls">
  <select name="year_level" id="year_level">
   <option> </option>
   <option>First Year</option>
   <option>Second Year</option>
   <option>Third Year</option>
   <option>Fourth Year</option>
   <option>Grade 11</option>
   <option>Grade 12</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your response and it will help me for my project thank you.

Comment: Made code more readable; removed duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you have already, you need to add an `onchange` listener to the course element.

```
document.getElementById("course").onchange = function() {}
```

Then add ID's to the grade 11 and grade 12 options, so that you can find them in the DOM.

```
<option id="grade-11">Grade 11</option>
<option id="grade-12">Grade 12</option>
```

Finally, listen to the onchange value and modify the options accordingly.

```
document.getElementById('course').onchange = function() {
  if (["BSCS", "BSIT"].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
        document.getElementById("grade-11").setAttribute("disabled", true);
        document.getElementById("grade-12").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
        document.getElementById("grade-11").removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementById("grade-12").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

That's it! The option elements can take the disabled attribute and cannot be selected when the course element is "BSCS" or "BSIT"

**Full code**

```js
var disable_options = false;
document.getElementById('type').onchange = function () {
   //alert("You selected = "+this.value);
   if(this.value == "Student")
   {
      document.getElementById('course').removeAttribute('disabled');
      document.getElementById('year_level').removeAttribute('disabled'); 
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById('course').setAttribute('disabled', true);
      document.getElementById('year_level').setAttribute('disabled', true);
   }
}

document.getElementById('course').onchange = function() {
  if (["BSCS", "BSIT"].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
  document.getElementById("grade-11").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  document.getElementById("grade-12").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
  document.getElementById("grade-11").removeAttribute("disabled");
  document.getElementById("grade-12").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Type:</label>
 <div class="controls">
     <select name="type" id="type" required>
      <option></option>
      <option>Student</option>
      <option>Teacher</option>
      <option>Staff</option>
      <option></option>
            </select>
 </div>
</div>
 
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Course Type:</label>
 <div class="controls">
  <select name="course" id="course" required>
   <option></option>
   <option>BSIT</option>
   <option>BSCS</option>
   <option>BSHRM</option>
   <option>BSBM</option>
   <option>BSTM</option>
   <option>STEM</option>
   <option>TOP</option>
   <option>GAS</option>
   <option>HUMSS</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>    
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Year Level:</label>
    <div class="controls">
  <select name="year_level" id="year_level">
   <option> </option>
   <option>First Year</option>
   <option>Second Year</option>
   <option>Third Year</option>
   <option>Fourth Year</option>
   <option id="grade-11">Grade 11</option>
   <option id="grade-12">Grade 12</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks my friend you deserve thumbs up for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

First add `value="value"` to the `<option>` elements, so you can read the values consistently. ie: `<option value="bsit">BSIT</option>`, `<option value="grade12">Grade 12</option>`, etc.

```
document.getElementById('course').addEventListener('change', function(){

  if(this.value && this.value.substr(0, 2) === 'bs'){

    // if a "bs" option is selected, disable grade 11 and 12 options

    document.querySelector('[value="grade11"]').setAttribute('disabled', '');
    document.querySelector('[value="grade12"]').setAttribute('disabled', '');

  }else{

    // remove all disabled attributes from options

    var disabledOptions = document.querySelectorAll('option[disabled]'),
        i, l = disabledOptions.length;

    for(i = 0; i < l; ++i){

      disabledOptions[i].removeAttribute('disabled');

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks my friend you did it!